# Checking when an XML File is uploaded with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I manage a website that pulls data in from an XML file, the file is updated every night around midnight. I am trying to write a simple piece of code that says on the website, File Last Updated: something something. After poking around and trying several different solutions, (I tried several variations using FileInfo to no avail) I decided to post here.

I tried Both GetCreationTime and GetLastWriteTime with FileInfo but I keep getting back 12/30/1600 or something similar no where near the correct date. When the file gets uploaded it just overwrites the old one so I wasn't sure which method to use either.

Current Filinfo Code:

```
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("feed/VEHICLES.XML");
    DateTime timeOfCreation = fileInfo.CreationTime;
    modifieddate.Text = timeOfCreation.ToString();
```

this returns 12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM but it should be 11/14/2011 1:41 AM

Comment: its at feed/VEHICLES.XML

Comment: Can you post the FileInfo related code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a relative path without knowing what the current directory is.

You probably want `Server.MapPath("~/feed/VEHICLES.XML")`.
If the file isn't in your application directory, you'll need to find its absolute path.

Comment: yeah that was it, guess i thought it would have thrown an error as appose to just returning a date like that, thanks ill mark this as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 3):

The file doesn't exist because the path is bad.

You can check `fileInfo.Exists` if it returns false then you get `12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM` for the timeOfCreation